# ggplot2 -- Forcing a 10^0 in a log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add the values '10^0' and '10^7' to the graph below. However, I can't seem to get either of the values to show on the graph. Any help would be appreciated.

The scale function I am using is

```
    scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
               labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```

Full Code is below the image.

[image]

```
ggplot(data=mydata.long, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=BenchMark, shape=BenchMark, colour=BenchMark)) + 
    geom_line(aes(linetype=BenchMark), size=1) +     # Set linetype by sex
    geom_point(size=3, fill="white") +         # Use larger points, fill with white
    scale_colour_hue(name="BenchMark",      # Set legend title
                     l=30)  +                  # Use darker colors (lightness=30)
    scale_shape_manual(name="BenchMark",
                       values=c("#CC0000", "#006600", "#669999", "#00CCCC", 
                             "#660099", "#CC0066", "#FF9999", "#FF9900", 
                             "black", "black", "black", "black", "black")) +      # Use points with a fill color
    scale_linetype_discrete(name="BenchMark") +
    xlab("Pipeline stage") + ylab("Number of comparisons") + # Set axis labels
    ggtitle("The number of tests identified\n at each pipeline stage\n in a two stage pipeline") +     # Set title
    theme_bw() +       # Position legend inside
    scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                   labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```

Comment: Can't you just do something like `scale_y_log10(limits=c(10^0, 10^7), breaks=10^(0:7))`?

Comment: Also, did you mean to say "zero value" in your title. You can't transform zero on a log scale, since log(0) = -Inf, but you can (in principle) have any value greater than log(0).

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to post it as an answer and ill accept it.

Comment: Done. See answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
scale_y_log10(limits=c(10^0, 10^7), breaks=10^(0:7))
```